# Command to squash currently staged changes into last commit without interactive rebase

Tags: git, reset, rebase, squash

say I have a commit "Added API endpoint", and I forgot to add documentation to that endpoint.
I add that documentation, and I want those changes to be within that "Added API endpoint" commit.

My current workflow is:

```bash
git commit -m "Squash this please"
git rebase -i @\~2

pick AAA "Added API endpoint"
s BBB "Squash this please"  # Changed the `pick` to `s` to squash into other commit
```

I do that quite often. Is there a better way to do this?
A single command which squashes the currently staged changes into the last commit without the need for a new, temp commit?

I also tried the workflow of removing the last commit with `git reset @~1`, which puts its changes together with the new changes and then just recommiting with `git commit -m "Added API endpoint"`, but this does not work well: If there are other unstaged changes I have to separate the "Added API endpoint" changes from them after the reset.

And this way feels less safe using `reset` instead of `rebase`.

**Answer**

As [ElpieKay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6330106/elpiekay) pointed out in a comment to this question: `git commit --amend --no-edit` does exactly that. Thank you!

(The duplicate flag is wrong imho)

Comment: To add more changes to the last commit, you can use `git add` and `git commit --amend`. `--no-edit` can be used if the commit message keeps the same.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+amend+last+commit

Comment: Thank you @ElpieKay! Does exactly what I was looking for <3